# Which encoding does application/dns-message use?

Tags: javascript, http, https, dns, dns-over-https

I am writing DNS-over-HTTPS server which should resolve custom names, not just proxy them to some other DoH server, like Google's. I am having trouble properly decoding the body of the request.

For example, I get body of request, that is in binary format, specifically in javascript in Uint8 ArrayBuffer type. I am using the following code to get base64 format of the array:

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return btoa(binary);
}
```

And I get something like this as a result:

> AAABAAABAAAAAAABCmFwbngtbWF0Y2gGZG90b21pA2NvbQAAAQABAAApEAAAAAAAAE4ADABKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

Now, per [RCF8484](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8484) standard this should be decoded as base64url, but when I decode it as such, I get the following:

> apnx-matchdotomicom)NJ

I also used this ["tutorial"](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/wireformat) as the reference, but they also decode similarly formatted blob and I get similar nonsense like previously.

There is very little to no information about something like this on the internet and if it is of any help DoH standard uses application/dns-message media type for the body.

If anyone has some insight on what I am doing wrong or how I could edit the question to make it more clear, please help me, cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the RFC:

> 6. Definition of the "application/dns-message" Media Type
>
> The data payload for the "application/dns-message" media type is a
> single message of the DNS on-the-wire format defined in Section 4.2.1
> of [RFC1035], which in turn refers to the full wire format defined in
> Section 4.1 of that RFC.

So what you get is exactly what is sent on the wire in the normal DNS over 53 case.

I would recommend you use a DNS library that should have a `from_wire` or similar method to which you can feed this content and get back some structured data.

Showing an example in Python with the content you gave:

```
In [1]: import base64

In [3]: import dns.message

In [5]: payload = 'AAABAAABAAAAAAABCmFwbngtbWF0Y2gGZG90b21pA2NvbQAAAQABAAApEAAAAAAAAE4ADABKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA='

In [7]: raw = base64.b64decode(payload)

In [9]: msg = dns.message.from_wire(raw)

In [10]: print msg
id 0
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags RD
edns 0
payload 4096
option Generic 12
;QUESTION
apnx-match.dotomi.com. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

So your message is a DNS query for the `A` record type on name `apnx-match.dotomi.com.`

Also about:

> I am writing DNS-over-HTTPS server which should resolve custom names,

If you don't do that to learn (which is a fine goal), note that there are already various open source nameservers software that do DOH so you don't need to reinvent it. For example: https://blog.nlnetlabs.nl/dns-over-https-in-unbound/

Comment: Thank you for Your answer, I wasn't decoding the response as a DNS packet, but rather just as a string, which honestly was very silly of me. I have a greater understanding of the protocol now. And regarding the library, if anybody is interested, there is this amazing Javascript library for encoding and decoding DNS packets, it's called dns-packet and can be found on npm. Cheers :))